# clearSession() in auth0 redirecting to auth0 page

Tags: react-native, session, auth0

I am using auth0 for my react native app, login authentication. Problem is everytime I use clearSession() it will redirect to auth0 for a brief moment then only will show my InitialScreen. How can I directly redirect to the InitialScreen?

```
  const onPressLogout = async () => {

   try {
       await clearSession();
       dispatch(UserActionLogout());//this is where my IntialScreen displaying
   } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
   }
};
```

I want after user click logout, just redirect to InitialScreen. I  am using react-native-auth0

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour. The session is stored in the authorization server as Single Sign-on cookie.

> To log the user out, redirect them to the Auth0 log out endpoint by importing and calling the clearSession method from the useAuth0 hook. This method removes their session from the authorization server.

[Add logout to your app](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native/00-login#add-logout-to-your-app)

For more information about [Logout](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/logout) process.